# How does conda manage python pkgs?

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda

I am a newbie to conda(on Linux ubuntu). I'm confused with the way of conda virtual environments managing python pkgs. So I did some tests:

I create 2 virtual env: `ros` and `ros-copy` for python2.7

In `ros`and `ros-copy`envs,
run python scripts:

```py
import sys
for p in sys.path:
    print(p)
```

shell prints the available py module pathes:

```sh
`ros`
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros/lib/python27.zip
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros/lib/python2.7
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/home/zhixin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros/lib/python2.7/site-packages


`ros-copy`
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros-copy/lib/python27.zip
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros-copy/lib/python2.7
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros-copy/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros-copy/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros-copy/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros-copy/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/home/zhixin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/ros-copy/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

both include `/home/zhixin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

`conda install numpy` will install numpy into current env path `/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/$(env_name)/lib/python2.7`

`pip install numpy` will install numpy into `/home/zhixin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

So I believe **using `pip` in conda env can't seperate the dependency of different envs**

Meanwhile, **`apt` install python pkgs in system-wide path. So you can't use `apt` to manage conda env pkgs seperately either**

**The only way is using `conda install`**

Am I right? If so, **what's the point of using `pip` in conda env?**

Comment: [...] `pip install numpy` will install numpy into `/home/zhixin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` [...] this is not how it should be. There can be multiple reasons for that, two come to my mind right now: 1) you don't have pip installed in the environment 2) your path (cache) is messed up - you didn't restart your shell and didn't run `hash -r` after creating the environment. Quick workaround: use `python -m pip install <pkg-name>` after activating should make sure the right pip is called.

Comment: @cel Thank you! I think it is because i didn't run `hash -r`. Another question: however I find if I create a new env after run `hash -r`, `pip` still works fine (install pkg into `/home/zhixin/miniconda3/envs/$(env_name)/lib/python2.7`). How can I know when should I run this command?

Comment: Very rarely to almost never. It happened to me once or twice that right after installing anaconda the path still was not updated. Safest is always to close your shell and reopen right after a fresh installation. Afterwards you should not need it anymore.